# Spring-boot application test - memory issues

Tags: java, spring

I have a spring-boot test that starts my application and run some tests on it.

I am having a problem setting the application heap size.

When I run it through maven and surefire with memory parameters set, it all works, but trying to run it from my IDE (Intellij) doesn't, and I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyTest {

    public MyTest(String name, URL url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters...
    public static Iterable<Object[]> tests() throws IOException {
       ....
    }

    @Before
    public void setUpContext() throws Exception {
        new TestContextManager(getClass()).prepareTestInstance(this);
    }


    @Test
    public void doSomething() throws Exception {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your run configuration, and set the memory options.

Comment: Have you configured the heap size of your IDE like this post [Configuring JVM options and platform properties](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties)?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it, but I did set the memory parameters on the run configuration. They just seem to not be passed to the VM that runs the application for the test.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Apparently, the surefire plugin definition on my pom has precedence over intellij run configurations.

I needed -Xmx1024 but it was:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
               </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: `-XX:MaxPermSize` that only works on Java 7 and older